# Congruence radius of taylor series of complicated functions, for example $(x+2)^{((x+2)^{x+2})}$ at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Lets say , I want to determine the congruence radius of the taylor series of $$f(x)=(x+2)^{((x+2)^{x+2})}$$ at the point $x=0$.

The expansion apparently has large coefficients, so I wonder what the convergence radius is.

> How can I calculate the convergence radius in such cases ? Is there a numerical method ?

Comment: I enjoy the *apparently* ! By the way, what do you think about my answer to the problem of three roots ? Just out of curiosity. Cheers.

Comment: The coefficients have very long formulae but they are not so huge when evaluated numerically.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Seems that the coefficients tend to $0$, which is not what I expected by looking at the first $100$ terms.

Comment: I shall check tomorrow.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici After having quickly read the answer, you seem to have shown the three roots and that the "middle" is the desired fix-point. This was the question in the title. Can you also show that the fix-point-iteration will never converge to the middle root ? This is the final goal of the question.